# Scala Slick - Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) on query results

Tags: scala, post, recursion, stack-overflow, slick

I am playing around with Slick on top of a Twitter Finatra application. Finally I thought I made it but now, when I want to process a result, I always get an recursion error. I looked around but I did not find anything helpful for this particular problem. The code I have is actually quite simple:

Map the Database class to a custom Type:

```
package com.configurationManagement.library

package object Types {
  type SlickDatabase = slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api.Database
}
```

Model:

```
package com.configurationManagement.app.domain

import slick.lifted.Tag
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.profile.SqlProfile.ColumnOption.NotNull

case class ConfigurationTemplate(id: Option[Int], name: String)

class ConfigurationTemplates(tag: Tag) extends Table[ConfigurationTemplate](tag: Tag, "configuration_template") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name", NotNull)
  def uniqueNameIndex = index("unique_name", name, unique = true)

  def * = (id.?, name) <> (ConfigurationTemplate.tupled, ConfigurationTemplate.unapply)
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.configurationManagement.app.controller

import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates
import com.configurationManagement.app.dto.request.RequestConfigurationTemplateDto
import com.configurationManagement.library.Types._
import com.twitter.finatra.http.Controller
import com.twitter.inject.Logging
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

@Singleton
class ConfigurationTemplateController @Inject()(database: SlickDatabase)
  extends Controller with Logging with FutureConverter {

  post("/configurations/templates") { dto: RequestConfigurationTemplateDto =>
    val templates = TableQuery[ConfigurationTemplates]
    val query = templates.filter(_.id === 1)
    response.ok(query.map(_.name))
  }
}
```

And here comes the error

```
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast.TableNode["driver_table"]->com.configurationManagement.app.domain.ConfigurationTemplates["table_node"]->slick.ast
```

Obvisously this line causes the error:

```
query.map(_.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things I see, first you need to add `.result` to the query to transform it into a `FixedSqlStreamingAction`, second you need a database to run that query on:

```
private[this] val database: slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend.DatabaseDef = Database.forDataSource(...)

database.run(templates.filter(_.id === 1).map(_.name).result)
```

Which returns a `Future[Seq[String]]`, this probably is the expected type from `response.ok`.